# Getting data from MySQL through PHP - am I doing it right?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Simple question I guess, but a fundamental one and I'm not sure of the best practice.

So let's say that I have a database with some IP addresses that I want to display to the user.

Is this a good/secure way/practice?

```
//--> CONNECT TO DB, etc

$db_query = 'SELECT ip,'
        ."FROM table "
        ."GROUP BY ip ";

$result = $db_conn->query($db_query);
echo 'Found '.$result->num_rows.' records';

if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        //POPULATE A HTML TABLE/WHATEVER WITH THE INFO
    }
}
```

I'm mostly concerned about this: `$result->num_rows > 0` and this: `fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)`

I'm asking because I read somewhere that `num_rows > 0` can usually mean trouble depending on the situation, for example a user login. In that case I suppose it would `num_rows == 1` right?

And also, I haven't fully understood the difference between MYSQLI_BOTH and other forms of fetching.. If you could simple explain them to me and when to use them I would be grateful.

What do you think?

Comment: Looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Looks ok but some code missing in your question above. Guess you want to add a bold text or something like that. Anyway it looks ok. Depend what you really want if you will group by the same IP address you will just get one result so maybe you dont really need WHILE but it will also work with one result so it's ok.

Comment: Hello Eric and StudioArena, I have edited the question above adding two specific issues. If you could take a look again... StudioArena, let's assume for this specific query that I'll get more than one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a check to ensure your query was executed OK - and if not output the error :

```
$result = $db_conn->query($db_query);
// check for error - output the error
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $db_query;
    die($message);
}
echo 'Found '.$result->num_rows.' records';
```

Other than that ... looks OK

EDIT:

To explain MYSQLI_BOTH, the options are MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH ->

- **MYSQLI_ASSOC** = Associative array so the value of the rows can be accessed using `$row['column']`
- **MYSQLI_NUM** = Numeric array so the values of the rows are accessed using a number `$row[n]` where n is the number of the column (0 based)
- **MYSQLI_BOTH** = can use both to access values of row either `$row[n]` or `$row['column']`

EDIT2:

There is also a function for checking the number of returned rows :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){ 
   echo "Sorry. No records found in the database";                        
} 
else { 
  // loop you results or whatever you want to do
}
```

EDIT3:

[php.net has some excellent docs for the MY_SQLI extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If you only need an associative array, then don't use `fetch_array()`. Use `fetch_assoc()`.
2. There's no need to concatenate the query like that, you could use something like:

   $sql = "

   ```
   SELECT
       ip
   FROM
       table
   ```

   ";

This helps with large queries with multiple options in the WHERE clause or JOINs. It's quicker to type out, and you can quickly copy and paste it for checking in phpMyAdmin and the like.